# Appium not performing any action in Web View of ios real device

Tags: ios, appium

I am working on a hybrid app. Immediatly after opening the app i need to switch to webview. I am able to switch to webview successfully, but Appium not able to interact with webelement(findElement not responding in webview). The same code is working fine with ios simulator and Android emulator, I face this issue in ios realdevice.

I have also  installed **ios-webkit-debug-proxy**. In desired capabilities also I am using startIWDP as true. Please give me a solution. Web Inspector has also been turned on in real device.

***Xcode version - 11
ios version -13
Appium version - 1.15.1***

Please find below log after switching to webview

[W3C (6f564330)] Calling AppiumDriver.getCurrentContext() with args: **["6f564330-b253-4adb-a0a1-839720186f32"]**

[XCUITest] Executing command 'getCurrentContext'

[W3C (6f564330)] Responding to client with driver.getCurrentContext() result: **"WEBVIEW_1267.1"**

[HTTP] <-- GET /wd/hub/session/6f564330-b253-4adb-a0a1-839720186f32/context 200 2 ms - 26

[HTTP]

[HTTP] --> POST /wd/hub/session/6f564330-b253-4adb-a0a1-839720186f32/element

[HTTP] {"using":"id","value":"login-button"}

[W3C (6f564330)] Calling AppiumDriver.findElement() with args: **["id","login-button","6f564330-b253-4adb-a0a1-839720186f32"]**

[XCUITest] Executing command 'findElement'

[BaseDriver] Valid locator strategies for this request: xpath, id, name, class name, -ios predicate string, -ios class chain, accessibility id

[BaseDriver] Waiting up to 0 ms for condition

[RemoteDebugger] Executing atom 'find_element'

[RemoteDebugger] Executing 'find_element' atom in default context

[RemoteDebugger] Sending javascript command: '(function(){return function(){var k=this;functi...'

[RemoteDebugger] Sending '_rpc_forwardSocketData:' message to app 'PID:1267', page '1', target 'page-6' (id: 8)

Answer (score 0):

I presume when you say you are using Appium 1.15.1 you also mean desktop and server. I had the same problem until I started using appium server 1.16.0.
Also I used the newest version of the appium-webdriveragent 2.5.4 with server 1.16.0.

So I basically patched the appium server with this new appium-webdriveragent. And then patched the appium desktop with the new server. 
If you need help with this, let me know. Because the structure took me a while to understand.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue on Appium 8.0.0 and iOS version 16.3

TouchActions solved my issue. Hope helping with you as well.

```
    WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//XCUIElementTypeButton[@label='Close']"));
    TouchActions action = new TouchActions(driver);
    action.click(element).perform();
```

Use Actions instead of TouchActions on Appium 8.3.0

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.click(element).perform();
```